# How to detect if a file upload is large than the maximum allowed

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if a file is large than the maximum allowed in the php.ini.  When I post a file that is large than the maximum size, the post is empty.  I've tried setting the post max size and the upload max size on the fly, but to no avail.  I'm working in the Zend framework, but don't see anything in the application.ini file that limits file upload size.

If I do:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    print_r($_FILES); die();
}
```

with a size smaller than the php.ini limit, the script dies.  If the file is large, the post is empty and the `die()` is not hit.  So is there something I'm missing?  How do I detect if the file is larger than the limit if the post is empty?

SOLVED:

```
if (array_key_exists('CONTENT_LENGTH', $_SERVER) && !$_FILES && !$_POST) {
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ini_set('post_max_size', '8M');` to set the max-post size to 8 megabytes.

Use `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');` to set the individual size of files to 8 megabytes - you can still post more than 8MB if you upload multiple files, which can be desirable.

If the file is 'too big' you will still get the posted file in `$_FILES` but there will be an error code and the temp-file wont be there if you look for it.

`$_FILES["file"]["error"]` can have one of these values: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Typically you'll write some `switch case` statement to deal with error codes.

Answer (score 3):

- If you exceed `upload_max_filesize` the `error` key contains 1 ([UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)).
- If you exceed `post_max_size`, both `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty.

Other than that, make sure you're able to see all error messages while developing.

Answer (score 2):

PHP file upload max size is determined by 3 configuration values in php.ini, namely upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit. You can get the maximum file size allowed in uploading by this snippet:

```
$max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
$upload_mb = min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
if(($_FILES["file"]["size"] > $upload_mb)){die();}else{ echo "smaller value"}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `memory_limit`, that makes no sense at all. Only if you're going to read the file into memory completely then you might as well just limit on `upload_max_filesize`.